# Stop-Service Cmdlet not able to open service that exists

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to write a PowerShell script to stop services on the local machine.

When I run the get-service cmdlet it works as expected. When I use the stop-service cmdlet, It errors stating that no service exists with the name I specify. If this was true surely the get-service cmdlet would throw the same error.

```
Get-Service "Service 1" # Returns Service and status
Stop-Service "Service 1" # Throws error below:

Stop-Service : Service 'Service 1' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot open Service 1 service on computer '.'.
```

Is there a trick when using the stop-service cmdlet?

Comment: Ignore me I was being thick. Had to run as an admin. Works fine now.

Comment: Change the title ("not able to open" instead of "find") and answer the question yourself

Answer (score 47):

Solution was to run PowerShell as an administrator. Stop-Service worked ok after doing that.

Comment: This worked thanks. But does anyone have an idea how to make it not require the PS console ran as Administrator?

Comment: @tolache. You have two options. When the powershell is open rightclick on the taskbar icon and select 'run as administrator'. Or use this super fancy shortcut: windows-x, a