# Service cannot be started due to the following error: Cannot open service on computer '.'

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to Start a service using Powershell and using the code below

```
function CheckServiceStatus {
param($winupdate)
$getservice = Get-Service -Name $winupdate

if($getservice.Status -ne $running){
    stop-service $winupdate
    Start-Service $winupdate 
    Write-output "Starting" $winupdate "service"|out-file "C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\abc.txt"
    Add-Content C:\Users\Mani\Desktop\abc.txt  $getservice.Status
    }
}
Read-Host -Prompt "Press Enter to exit"

#Variables

$winupdate = 'vsoagent.192.Shalem'
$running = 'Running'
CheckServiceStatus $winupdate
```

I got the following error:

> Service 'ABC' cannot be stopped due to the following error: Cannot
>   open ABC service on computer '.'

I found some [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37651152/cannot-start-service-on-computer) here on our forum but couldn't resolve. Please suggest

Comment: "cannot be stopped"? where exactly are you trying to stop the service in the code?

Comment: just updated the missing code....plz check @Avshalom

Comment: Have you tried running as Admin? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29146784/stop-service-cmdlet-not-able-to-open-service-that-exists

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to start/stop/etc services, you need elevated privileges (run as Admin). You can still get information about the service, but that's it. If you want to include a more verbose error, include this:

```bsh
$isadmin = [bool](([System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).groups -match "S-1-5-32-544")
if($isadmin){
   Write-Error "You need elevated privileges to run this script"
   exit(1)
}

...

Rest of your code
```

Or even better, if you're running Powershell 4.0 or higher (You can get it by checking `$PSVersionTable`), you can include

```bsh
#Requires -RunAsAdministrator
```

At the top of your file, and you won't be able to run it without admin privilages.

Comment: I up-voted this answer since it helped me.  It should be marked as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

Look into `Event Viewer` and find more details. In my case, I have found relevant info in `Administrative Events`, then `Service Control Manager`. The error was related to insufficient privileges given for the account. The service was creating a new file and this task failed. Of course, your error's details are probabably different, but that is the tip.

Answer (score -1):

I had this issue while running the command on PowerShell ISE. All I did was start the PowerShell ISE as an administrator.